# Validate FCKEditor blank or not

Tags: php, javascript, fckeditor

i am trying to validate using JavaScript if the fckeditor value is blank or not but with no luck.

i am creating the Editor using javascript :

```
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('txtMessage');
                                                 oFCKeditor.BasePath = "../fckeditor/";
                                                 oFCKeditor.ToolbarSet = "Default";
                                                oFCKeditor.Height = "500";
                                                  oFCKeditor.Value = "test";
                                                oFCKeditor.Create();
```

but when i use:

```
 if (document.form.txtMessage.value == "") {
      alert('You Must Enter a Message');
```

when the editor is empty and alerts me and i write something in it, it keeps alerting it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checksubmit() {        
            var FCKGetInstance = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('PageDescription');  
            var getText = FCKGetInstance.GetData(); 
            var StripTag = getText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
            if(StripTag=='') {
                alert("This is required field");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert(StripTag);
            }       
        }
     </script>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="javascript: return checksubmit();" />
```

Comment: i tried this one .didn't work . i get EditorInstance.EditorDocument.body.innerText is undefined

Comment: I have modified the script. please check again.

Comment: replace is for strip HTML tag as editor adds some html tags e.g <P>.

Comment: `var getText = FCKGetInstance.GetData()`

(This works in Rich Text and Source view)