# How to check if CKEDITOR textarea is empy

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I have a CKEDITOR Text area. The field will never be empty because the CKEDITOR always write

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

also if the field contains no user input.

Is there a way to check if the field is empty (no user input)?
Because: $_POST['textarea'] == '' returns false also if user input is null.

Comment: i m not sure but maybe You can use jquery validation for textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it consistently adds the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` how about this?

```
if (in_array($_POST['textarea'], array('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '')))
```

or:

```
if (str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $_POST['textarea']) == '')
```

This will also return true if the user inadvertently presses `enter`, but doesn't add any text.

EDIT:

You can take this as far as you like, depending on your notion of "empty input":

```
if (trim(str_replace('&nbsp', '', strip_tags($_POST['textarea']))) == '')
```

etc.

EDIT some more:

Turns out this has been discussed before: [Validate FCKEditor blank or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596884/validate-fckeditor-blank-or-not)

Comment: How about <span> with setted color and nothing written?

Comment: Well, you could also strip all the tags, whitespace and nbsp's and see if anything is left, just add as much as you think you need :)

Comment: I tried with your suggestion:
$i = str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $_POST['textarea']);
if ($i == ''){
echo 1;
}else{
echo 2;
}

I become 2, always... why?

Comment: Well, maybe there's something else in `$_POST['textarea']` as well? Try putting a `var_dump($_POST['textarea'], $i)` before your `if` statement, that will tell you what exactly is in those variables and how many characters are in there. If there's more than 0, you'll have to do some more replacing. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596884/validate-fckeditor-blank-or-not